# Why doesn't Windows 10 need a recovery image (like install.wim) to reset the system?

Tags: installation, windows-10, operating-systems, wim

Windows 8/8.1 requires a standalone recovery image to reset the system. But, Microsoft claimed that Windows 10 no longer needs it.
http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/03/16/how-windows-10-achieves-its-compact-footprint/
What's the mechanism behind this feature?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve specifically?  Given that Microsoft gave zero information what change with the mechanic, I would assume the process of moving your personal files and creating a Windows.old folder is simply skipped when the option to keep nothing is chosen.

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried to generate a install.wim using DISM for recovery purpose when I was using Windows 8.1.But, system refresh with my recovery image finally failed. I had to reinstall the system from scratch in the end. Now, I'm not sure whether a recovery image generated by "dism /capture-image" is useful to Windows 10.

Comment: It is useful if you normally boot to WinPE, partition your drives, and apply .WIM currently.  Of course that command isn't even the correct command.  If anything it would be something like `recimg /createimage C:\CustomRefreshImages\Image1`, I see no reason, it would have changed.  You can try `recimage /showcurrent` to see the current image.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I would try applying the image next time.